# DC-DC converter possible by using Zener breakdown as input to transistor gate?

Tags: voltage, transistors, ltspice, zener, source

Suppose you have a DC voltage source that is higher than required, in this example let's assume one wants a 12V voltage source from a 18V source. Would it be possible to have a circuit, where the source feeds a capacitor through a transistor, and when the capacitor is charged up to a defined voltage, the transistor blocks any further voltage buildup? I played around with a zener diode to specify the exact voltage where this shutoff should happen, but in LTSpice this does not work:

[image: How I would imagine the circuit]

What I imagine is that as soon as the voltage at C2 reaches > 12V, the zener diode D1 would break down and start conducting, which then turn on Q1, which finally turns off Q2. (Suppose that V1 and V2 are from the same voltage source, I just needed a voltage significantly higher than V2 to block Q2). The zener breakdown voltage is set to 12V, but the voltage near C1 is still at ~17V, so V1-diodedrop.
Is it possible to make such a circuit work, and if that's the case, how is it called, and how would a mosfet version look like? I tried using a depletion mode mosfet instead of Q2, but such a depletion mode mosfet is not available in the LTSPice library.

Comment: Why can't you use an NPN emitter follower with the Zener connected from base to 0 volts and a resistor from collector to base (3 components).

Comment: This sounds like you're trying to make a simple hysteretic converter, which can be done but requires a different topology than this.

Comment: Your solution surely does the job, but depending on how much higher the input voltage is compared to the desired output voltage, the resistor/npn transistor might dissipate a lot of heat. Imagine that I only want to periodically charge up the capacitor and otherwise completely shut down Q2.

Comment: I haven't attempted to analyze your circuit, but my reading of your text description seems to imply that you think zener breakdown occurs as a kind-of 'avalanche' effect, where the zener behavior changes abruptly between an 'open switch' to a 'closed switch' as the voltage across it crosses its zener breakdown value. Is this a fair description of how you think the zener will behave?

Comment: @brhans yes, but isn't that exactly how zener diodes are designed to work? That they have a rather steep voltage-to-current curve at a specific reverse biased voltage. Obviously this is not a digital on off, but for the purpose of using it to control a transistor/mosfet, isn't that good enough?

Comment: @luksen No, that's not how zeners work. Even an ideal zener never behaves as a 'closed switch'. After it reaches its spec'ed zener voltage and starts allowing current to flow (at the 'knee'), you'll still see that zener voltage across the device (unlike a closed switch where the voltage across it is zero).

Comment: Even if a zener did behave like you want it to, I can't see how Q1 would ever switch on. For an NPN BJT to switch on, its base voltage needs to be 0.7V higher than its emitter voltage so that current can flow through the BE junction, but you've got nothing feeding Q1's base which could raise it higher than its emitter.

Answer (score 1):

Q2 will be always on.

Q1 may be destroyed.

---

Initially, Q1 is off, Q2's base-emitter voltage is negative enough so Q2 turns on and C2 gets charged up through Q2. Once its voltage reaches somewhere above 12V the D1-D2 pair allows current flow to Q1's base.

So, Q1's base will see:

$$
V_{B-Q2}=V_{OUT}-12- V_F
$$

where \$V_{OUT}\$ is the output voltage (voltage across C2), \$V_F\$ is a diode drop (0.5 ~ 0.7 V).

The voltage above, Q1's BE diode, 18V supply and Q2's EB diode form a power-OR. So you have this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fXuJ0U.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Obviously, Q2's EB junction will win because it's coming from a higher voltage. So the Q2's base will see one diode drop less than 18V, **making Q2 always on regardless of the output voltage**.

Q1 is a 2N2222 having a maximum allowed EB voltage of 6V. As can be seen from the analysis above, the EB volage of Q1 will be ~12V which is way beyond the abs max ratings. This may result in destruction of Q1.

---

> Is it possible to make such a circuit work

It's unclear if you want to make a latched stop to cut the power to the capacitor(s) indefinitely once the voltage reaches a certain level (requires a power cycle to reset/clear the stop), or a regulator that "keeps" the voltage at certain level.

Comment: I want a regulator. The basic idea was to periodically charge the capacitor C1 through Q2, and to force Q2 to oscillate by using the zener as the control voltage at the Q2 base.